# How to return the value for last element greater than x

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
data_dict = {'obj': {0: 'obj1', 1: 'obj1', 2: 'obj1', 3: 'obj1', 4: 'obj1', 5: 'obj1', 6: 'obj1', 7: 'obj1', 8: 'obj2', 9: 'obj2', 10: 'obj2', 11: 'obj2', 12: 'obj2', 13: 'obj2', 14: 'obj2', 15: 'obj2', 16: 'obj3', 17: 'obj3', 18: 'obj3', 19: 'obj3', 20: 'obj3', 21: 'obj3', 22: 'obj3', 23: 'obj3'}, 'seq': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 1, 9: 2, 10: 3, 11: 4, 12: 5, 13: 6, 14: 7, 15: 8, 16: 1, 17: 2, 18: 3, 19: 4, 20: 5, 21: 6, 22: 7, 23: 8}, 'var': {0: 1900.0, 1: 3100.0, 2: 100.0, 3: 7800.0, 4: 1300.0, 5: 100.0, 6: 400.0, 7: 4800.0, 8: 1900.0, 9: 2600.0, 10: 600.0, 11: 7800.0, 12: 1300.0, 13: 100.0, 14: 400.0, 15: 4800.0, 16: 1900.0, 17: 2600.0, 18: 500.0, 19: 7900.0, 20: 1800.0, 21: 4800.0, 22: 300.0, 23: 300.0}, 'expected_output': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 5, 6: 5, 7: 8, 8: 1, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 4, 12: 5, 13: 5, 14: 5, 15: 8, 16: 1, 17: 2, 18: 2, 19: 4, 20: 5, 21: 6, 22: 6, 23: 6}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict).set_index(['obj', 'seq'])
```

With the `df` presented above, I'd like to create a column that for each row would return `seq` value of the last row where `var >= 800`, within each group defined by `obj` level of index. How can I do this?

Comment: Please add a *minimal* example. Also provide the expected output for that example.

Comment: perform your operation on this data    (df.tail(len(df))) to get last record

Comment: I have added `expected_output` column.

Comment: @jakes This is a bit circuitous. What is the actual, larger problem you are working on?

Comment: @jasonm The whole problem is too specific to describe it here so that it could be useful for anybody else than me. But generally, I've got additional variable (let's call it `my_var`) that is assumed to be valid if `var >= 800` within the same row, if not we should return last valid value. I wanted to return `seq` here as `my_var` is gathered into `seq`.

Comment: If you want it less circuitous, let's say I need to return the index of last value of `var` which is greater than 800 (within groups defined by `obj`)

Comment: @jakes the reason that I ask is that, at times, a `DataFrame` makes a very easy problem much harder. Is your data in this structure for any other reason? Can you calculate this metric prior to the DataFrame? Computationally, this is a very easy problem.

Comment: As I have other variables and I need to perform this operation within `groupby` I think it needs to be formed into `DataFrame`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I figured it out:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('obj', group_keys = False).apply(lambda x: (x['var'] >= 800).cumsum().rank(method = 'min'))
```

Caveat: this will work only with the values in`seq` iterating by 1 starting from 1.
If this is not the case we have to do some nasty hack like below:

```
df['new'] = df.reset_index().groupby('obj', group_keys = False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[(x['var'] >= 800).cumsum().rank(method = 'min').astype(int) - 1, 'seq'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward solution is to use `np.nan` together with `ffill()` method:

```
df['var2'] = np.where(df['var'] >= 800, df.index.get_level_values('seq'), np.nan)
df['var2'] = df.groupby('obj')['var2'].ffill().astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, though I assume you know num_objects in advance:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict).reset_index()
df['var'] = df['var'].astype('int64')
num_objects = 10
for j in range(1, num_objects):
    print (df[(df['var'] >= 800) & (df['obj'] == ('obj' + str(j)))][-1:]['seq'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition, and map `False` to `NaN` and `True` to `1`. Then with a multiplication and `cummax` (since `'seq'` is numeric monotonic increasing) we can get the last `'seq'` that met the condition within group. We forward fill within group to replace `NaN`. It's a little unfortunate that we use two groupbys, but this ensures the output column remains `NaN` until the first row that satisfies the condition within the `'obj'` group.

```
df['result'] = ((df['var'].ge(800).map({False: np.NaN, True: 1})
                 *df.index.get_level_values('seq'))
                 .groupby('obj').cummax()
                 .groupby('obj').ffill())
```